# YAML - Is there a difference between these two mapping structures?

Tags: yaml

I believe the following two structures are equivalent ways of specifying a map.

```
environment:
  VARIABLE_1: value1
  VARIABLE_2: value2
```

```
environment:
   - VARIABLE_1=value1
   - VARIABLE_2=value2
```

I believe both of these should be equivalent ways of specifying a map, which in JSON format would be this:

```
{
    "environment" : {
        "VARIABLE_1" : "value1",
        "VARIABLE_2" : "value2"
    } 
}
```

Is my understanding correct?

*Because I do not know the terminology in detail I could not perform a search to find an answer via duckduckgo or other search engine.*

I did however scan the docs and nothing obvious jumped out at me.

https://yaml.org/spec/1.2.2/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

no, first one is a like a dictionary in python or map in golang or ... in ... . second one is a like a list in python or a slice in golang or ... in ... . your json is equivalent version of map(first yaml example). your second yaml example would be something like this:

```json
{
  "environment": [
    "VARIABLE_1=value1",
    "VARIABLE_2=value2"
  ]
}
```

Comment: Thanks, it did seem a bit odd that there would be two ways to specify the same thing